# Set starting monitor for form in c++ cli

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

How can I properly set the starting screen for a specific form in Managed C++/cli?

The idea is to use the form_Load event, detect if a secondary screen is present and set the starting position.

I've seen some examples in C# but I can't use the Screen class in the same way, ie

This

```
Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;
```

cannot be translated to this in c++

```
Screen::AllScreens[1]->WorkingArea->Location;
```

Comment: I mean, it seems that in C++ I have different properties. I've edited the question @Adriano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`WorkingArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.workingarea.aspx) returns a [`Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx), which is a struct. Structs are value types, not reference types, therefore you use `.`, not `->`.

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Debug::WriteLine(Screen::AllScreens[1]->WorkingArea.Location);
    //                                                 ^
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> {X=0,Y=0}

Comment: That it! The editor shows an error with that code, "System::Object has no member WorkingArea", but it compiles. That was confusing. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting that Intellisense error as well. I'm not sure why Intellisense thinks that `AllScreens` is an array of `Object^`, but as you noted, it compiles fine.